# Is there a way to design a multi unit symbol in altium 21

Tags: schematics, altium

I was wondering if anyone know how to properly create a multi unit symbol in Altium for a transistor?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure someone does. Are you also wondering how to actually do this, or is knowing that *someone* knows how enough for you?

Comment: ^^ Funny guy.   $$$$  Whats the version you're using???  You do this in your own custom library.    When you have your library open for editing, instead of hitting "TOOLS/NEW COMPONENT"  try "TOOLS/NEW PART".   That's how you introduce new parts (new 'multi unit symbols') in V17 and earlier.   V18 and later would be similar but I can't tell you step by step

Comment: You draw it up in the schematic symbol editor...

Answer (score 3):

In Altium-speak, this is called a *Multi-Part Component*. It can be homogeneous (similar subsections like a 7404) or heterogeneous (different subsections like a FPGA). This can be found in Altium's [horrible documentation](https://resources.altium.com/p/your-altium-library-multiple-part-symbols-ease-your-design-time).

- Add a new symbol.
- *Tools -> New Part* will add subsections to your part. Do this as many times as necessary to create your subsections. The *SCH Library* panel will show you the different subsections which you can edit to your liking.

[image]
Screen capture from Altium showing multi-part component.

Comment: Thanks, now once a person has created something like this, how do they add the different parts into the schematic then? Doing drag and drop just gives the first part, part A.